# Unityを起動するたびに編集したPostProcessLayer.csが元に戻ってしまうのを止めるにはどうしたら良いか

Tags: unity3d

Mac11.1/Unity2019.4.19f1/Code1.53.0

まずこの問題の発端として、Unityコンソール上で

```
"When used with builtin render pipeline, Postprocessing package expects to be used on a fullscreen Camera.\nPlease note that using Camera viewport may result in visual artefacts or some things not working."
```

という警告が大量に出るようになった経緯があります。

URPやHDRPは使用しておらず、フルスクリーンではないカメラを使用しているので警告自体が出るのは分かりますが警告は不要なので出てほしくないと思い、

```
/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0.1/PostProcessing/Runtime/PostProcessLayer.cs
```

の約435行目、つまり直接警告を表示している部分、

```
Debug.LogWarning("When used with builtin render pipeline, Postprocessing package expects to be used on a fullscreen Camera.\nPlease note that using Camera viewport may result in visual artefacts or some things not working.", m_Camera);
```

をCodeでコメントアウトし、保存しました。

その時は問題は無くなるのですが、翌日Unityを起動するとアセットの読み込みなどが始まり保存したはずの435行目のコメントアウトが元の状態に戻っており警告が大量に出ます。またコメントアウトして保存すると消えますがまた翌日には元に戻っています。どうすれば変更したファイルが元に戻らなくなるのでしょうか？

unity 保存 ファイル 元に戻る
unity 起動時 読み込まない方法
などで検索しましたがそれらしき状況は見つかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnityEditorもしくはPluginが、自分自身を保護するための処理として、修復しているのでは？
また、アドレスには「PackageCache」とあります。キャッシュという名の通り、Unityの起動毎に自動生成しているファイルなのかもしれませんね。

起動毎に生成もしくは修正されているのだと仮定しましょう。そのあとに遅れて動くか、デバッグ開始時に自動起動する自前のエディタ拡張機能を作成してみるのはいかがでしょう。そのエディタ拡張機能でその行を消せばよさそうです。

[コンパイル完了時にトースト通知を表示するエディタ拡張](https://baba-s.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/11/24/113000)みたいなことをしていらっしゃる方もいますので、出来ると思います。デバッグ開始のイベントをどうやって発生させるか、もしくは、UnityEditor起動時に動くようにするにはどうするかが問題の要点になってきそうですね。

[ゲームを再生、停止した時にアセットを保存するエディタ拡張](https://baba-s.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/12/29/212500)を参考にすれば、デバッグ開始時に処理を実行することはできそうですね。

Comment: エディタ拡張はまだ触ったことがないのですが何とかできそうな気はします！